# Why is this JPanel not sticking to the specified size?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

So, I'm trying to learn Java Swing and custom components. I've created a JFrame, given it a background color, and added a JPanel:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1000, 2000);
    frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    jp.setSize(40, 40);
    frame.add(jp);

    frame.setVisible(true);
```

The result is a 1000x2000 window colored blue (as opposed to a white window with a 40x40 blue box inside it). Why is the JPanel expanding beyond its specified size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code, simply add one line to change the `LayoutManager` of the `JFrame`.  Then, when you add the component, it will keep it's preferred size.

Also, instead of calling `jp.setSize(40,40)`, call jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40,40)).

And, you need to call `pack()` on the `JFrame` to tell it to layout its components.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // New line of code
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 2000));  // Modified line of code
frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

JPanel jp = new JPanel();
jp.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40)); // Modified line of code
frame.add(jp);

frame.pack(); // added line of code
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Also, you should read up on all of the different `LayoutManagers` available to you.  [Here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) is a great tutorial.

Comment: When I run this the frame has 0 height. (Also, possible typo: FlowLatout = FlowLayout?)

Comment: @Ash, yeah....my bad.  Typos, and I forgot 2 modifications.  Added pack, and, also need to change the second set size call.

Comment: @Ash, please try the new version.

Comment: @Ash, thanks.  Sometimes I'm not as good of a compiler or JVM as I think I am.

Answer (score 2):

The default layout manager for a `JFrame` is [`BorderLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html). When you add a component to the frame without constraints, it uses `BorderLayout.CENTER` as the default constraint. This means the component takes up all available space, regardless of its requested size.

Comment: try using a GridBagLayout LayoutManager to get your desired results